# no remote video if localstream has no video webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm currently experiencing a problem that a client who has audio but no video can't receive the remote clients video (even though the remote client is capturing both audio and video).

Video and audio constraints are set to true on both clients. The application runs correctly if both clients have audio and video.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **make sure that the client who has audio/video MUST create offer**; and other client should create answer. Then *it will be oneway streaming*; and it will work!

```
userWhoHasMedia.createOffer(sdp_sucess_callback, sdp_failure_callback, sdp_constraints);

userWhoDontHavemedia.createAnswer(sdp_sucess_callback, sdp_failure_callback, sdp_constraints);
```

Also, if you want, you can set "`OfferToReceiveAudio`" and "`offerToReceiveVideo`" to false for client who doesn't captures media. Though, it is useless in your case, because non-Media client is receiver.

Comment: Thanks! Making the client who has the media make the offer did indeed fix the problem.